# Set spectrogram background to white

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to set the spectrogram image to white, and for the rest of the part, I would like it to be red scale.

I've tried `plt.imshow()`, using `cmap` as `'Reds'`. But the background remains red-ish. I hope it can be all white.

```py
a = gen_spectrograms(my_path)
plt.imshow(a, cmap = 'Reds', vmin = 0,  alpha = 1)
plt.show()
```

gen_spectrograms is a self-defined function.

Found some suggestions that I should use `clip`. But not sure how to use that. Or any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your background has value 0, you could use set_under:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = plt.cm.Reds
cm.set_under('white')
a=gen_spectrograms(my_path)
plt.imshow(a, cmap=cm, vmin=0.001)
plt.show()
```